# Node.js Cannot read Substring property

Tags: javascript, node.js, substring

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    var query = urlParser.parse(request.url).query;
    console.log(query);
    var searchTerm =query.substring(1).substring(0, temp.length-2);
    var bang = temp.substring(temp.length, temp.length-2);

    for (var engine in searchEngines){
        console.log(engine);
        if(bang == engine.bang){
            console.log("It's working !")
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First pass, I would say that your urlParser is coming up with null or undefined for your querystring. Have you stepped through with a debugger in any way? Console logged the different bits? What have you done so far to troubleshoot your issue?